# How to get non matching records form 12 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the code below but I did not get any result, please can anyone give me a suggestion.

`users_register` table have all user's mobile number, I have 12 tables like `property`, `hostels`, `hotels` and so on.

How to get not matched mobile numbers

```
SELECT t1.user_mobileno,
       t1.user_fullname
FROM users_register t1
LEFT JOIN userpostproperties t2 ON t1.user_mobileno = t2.property_contact_number
LEFT JOIN services t3 ON t1.user_mobileno=t3.contact_num
LEFT JOIN hostels t4 ON t1.user_mobileno=t4.h_contact_num
LEFT JOIN sales t5 ON t1.user_mobileno=t5.sales_contact
LEFT JOIN rentals t6 ON t1.user_mobileno=t6.rental_mobile
LEFT JOIN jobs t7 ON t1.user_mobileno=t7.emp_mobile
LEFT JOIN healthcare t8 ON t1.user_mobileno=t8.contact_num
LEFT JOIN education t9 ON t1.user_mobileno=t9.edu_mobile
LEFT JOIN hotels t10 ON t1.user_mobileno=t10.contact_num
LEFT JOIN restaurant t11 ON t1.user_mobileno=t11.contact_num
LEFT JOIN finance t12 ON t1.user_mobileno=t12.contact_no
LEFT JOIN manufacturer t15 ON t1.user_mobileno=t15.contact_no
```

Comment: Without knowledge of what you have and what you want nobody can help you

Comment: Horrible table aliases... I'd suggest abbreviations instead, e.g. `ur` for `users_register` and `f` for `finance`.

Comment: what is the issue according to above query if users_register contain data at least those information should be visible

Comment: You select columns from `t1` only and **LEFT** join the whole bunch of other tables. As the result you just replicate *some* records. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

To get the non matching records from `users_register` table, you can use `LEFT JOIN` with column name `IS NULL` in `WHERE` clause.

Is this you are expecting

```
SELECT t1.user_mobileno,
       t1.user_fullname
FROM users_register t1
LEFT JOIN userpostproperties t2 ON t1.user_mobileno = t2.property_contact_number
LEFT JOIN `services` t3 ON t1.user_mobileno = t3.contact_num
LEFT JOIN hostels t4 ON t1.user_mobileno = t4.h_contact_num
LEFT JOIN sales t5 ON t1.user_mobileno = t5.sales_contact
LEFT JOIN rentals t6 ON t1.user_mobileno = t6.rental_mobile
LEFT JOIN jobs t7 ON t1.user_mobileno = t7.emp_mobile
LEFT JOIN healthcare t8 ON t1.user_mobileno = t8.contact_num
LEFT JOIN education t9 ON t1.user_mobileno = t9.edu_mobile
LEFT JOIN hotels t10 ON t1.user_mobileno = t10.contact_num
LEFT JOIN restaurant t11 ON t1.user_mobileno = t11.contact_num
LEFT JOIN finance t12 ON t1.user_mobileno = t12.contact_no
LEFT JOIN manufacturer t15 ON t1.user_mobileno = t15.contact_no
WHERE   t2.property_contact_number IS NULL AND 
        t3.contact_num IS NULL AND 
        t4.contact_num IS NULL AND 
        t5.sales_contact IS NULL AND 
        t6.rental_mobile IS NULL AND
        t7.emp_mobile IS NULL AND
        t8.contact_num IS NULL AND
        t9.edu_mobile IS NULL AND
        t10.contact_num IS NULL AND
        t11.contact_num IS NULL AND
        t12.contact_no IS NULL AND
        t15.contact_no IS NULL
```